# Is there a python coding that can access and change the cell's alphabet to its opposite from in excel?

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I'm new to python and I need to make a program that changes the letter's in the cell to the opposite form and also know the amount of names in the column and which row the name list is at so that it can change all of the names. The code is for me to be able to change the names without to ever look at the name list due to privacy reasons. I'm currently using Pycharm and Openpyxl if anyone is wondering. The picture shows the before and after of how it should look like. I have done a few tries but after that, I just can't seem to get any ideas on how to change the alphabet. I also tried the replacement (replacement = {'Danial' = 'Wzmrzo'}) function however I am required to look at the name list and then be able to change the letters.

```
 import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
print("Type the file name:")
DF = input()
wb = load_workbook(DF + '.xlsx')
print("Sheet Name:")
sht = input()
ws = wb[sht]

NC = str(input("Where is the Name Column?"))
column = ws[ NC ]
column_list = [column[x].value for  x in range(len(column))]

print(column_list)
wb.save(DF + '.xlsx')
```

#### Before

[image: Before]

#### After

[image: After]

Comment: have you tried pandas library?

Comment: no never heard about it before is it similar to Openpyxl?

Comment: It can handle all types of files easily, including excel, check it out in case it is useful for you. I am still learning python so I cant say anything about openpyxl since I never used it. [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Warning I'm not too familiar with openpyxl and how they access rows/cols but it seems to have changed a lot in the last few years. So this should give you an idea for how to make it work but might not work exactly as written depending on your version.

To find the name column you could use

```
name_col = False
# loop along the top row looking for "Name"
for i,x in enumerate(ws.iter_cols(max_row=1)):
  if x[0].value == "Name":
    name_col = i + 1 # enumerate is 0 indexed, excel rows/cols are 1 indexed
    break
if name_col:
  # insert name changing code here
else:
  print("'Name' column not found.")
```

To change the names you could use (insert this in the code above)

```
# loop down name column
for i,x in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_col = name_col, max_col = name_col)):
  # we need to skip the header row so
  if i == 0:
    continue
  name = x[0].value
  new_name = ""
  for c in name:
    # ord() gets the ASCII value of the char, manipulates it to be the opposite then uses chr() to get back the character
    if ord(c) > 90:
        new_c = chr(25 - (ord(c) - 97) + 97)
    else:
        new_c = chr(25 - (ord(c) - 65) + 65)
    new_name.append(new_c)
  ws.cell(row=i+1, column=name_col).value = new_name # enumerate is 0 indexed, excel rows/cols are 1 indexed hence i+1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping but it seems there's an issue with the coding. It keeps saying column not found

Comment: @R4f trying `print(x[0].value)` before the `if x[0].value == "Name":` and see what it outputs. It might be that it's not iterating the correct row, or "Name" might not be the exact content of the cell.